# Как удалить лишние символы

Tags: python

В файле txt есть даты со значением в конце в виде:
06-24-2013:3.645
Как мне прочитать из файла построчно все даты и убрать символы тире и двоеточие чтобы я смог обрабатывать значения по индексам? В итоге должны получиться списки в виде:
['06', '24', '2013', '3.645']
Мне нужно посчитать среднее изменение цены ежемесячно, при том что в месяце бывает 4 или 5 недель.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: почему бы просто не сделать все через pandas, быстрее и удобнее

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
arr = []
with open('file.txt','r') as file:
    for i in file:
        arr.extend(re.findall(r'(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+):(\w.\w+)',i))
print(arr)
# Тем самым мы получаем массив arr с этими значениями
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо!

Comment: Учтите, что если после даты будет указано не однозначное число (допустим, `123.456`), то строка не подойдет под выражение и данные будут потеряны.

Comment: **Второе**: `\w.` соответствует не **буква**точка, а **буква**любой_символ. Из за этого выражение может принять многозначное число без точки (да, это можно считать фичей для обработки целых чисел, но, судя по задаче, вы пытались добиться не такого результата).

Comment: **И последнее**: при работе с группами захвата метод `findall()` возвращает список кортежей с совпадениями. В этом случае `arr.extend()` будет добавлять в список именно кортежи. То есть вы получите не `['06', '24', '2013', '3.645']`, а `[('06', '24', '2013', '3.645')]`. Эту особенность удобно использовать, если нужно группировать много дат в одном массиве